# PythonでURLDispatchを行うには？

Tags: python

API的な事を実現したいのですが、PythonでDjangoなどの大掛かりなFrameworkを使用せずにURLDispatchを行うには、どのように実装すれば良いのでしょうか？

Comment: s/API的な事/RESTなどのWeb API/ ? 実現したい処理内容を具体化または例示された方が、より有用な回答が付きやすいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

URLとビューのマッピングということであれば、 [WebDispatch](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WebDispatch/) ではどうでしょう？

Answer (score 1):

ご自分で実装するとなると、PATH_INFO に入っている値と呼び出したい view をマッピングするようなもの作れば良いと思います。
単純なのであれば↓のような感じでしょうか。
https://github.com/heavenshell/py-autodoc/blob/master/tests/app.py#L36

ただこういうのを自分で作るのではなく、takayuki-shimizukawa さんが書かれているようなライブラリや、WebOB や Werkzeug のようなものを使うのをお勧めします。
http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.9/

Answer (score 0):

Pythonではウェブサーバがウェブアプリを呼び出すときのAPIが定義されています。この規格に従っていればApacheでもNginxでもおなじアプリを動かすことができます。これをWSGIと呼びます。WSGIのアプリとは次のようにenvironとstart_responseの二つの引数をとる関数です。

URL Dispatchをやるためには`environ['PATH_INFO']`にpathが格納されているので、この文字列に従って場合分けをし、それぞれの文字列を返せば良いことになります。

```
def hello_world_app(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK' # HTTP Status
    headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain')] # HTTP Headers

    # ここでPATH_INFOに従って返答を作る
    path_info = environ['PATH_INFO']
    if path_info == '/':
       response = 'index!'
    elif path_info == '/secret':
       response = 'secret!'
    else:
        # 見つからない場合は404を返す
        start_response('404 not found', headers)
        return ['the page you looked for was not found']

    start_response(status, headers)
    return [response]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
    httpd = make_server('', 8000, hello_world_app)
    print "Serving on port 8000..."

    # Serve until process is killed
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

HTTPメソッドまで対応するなら@heavenshellさんの回答のリンクをみてください。